# Knockout js lots of custom bindings

Tags: knockout.js

What would be considered a good way of handling lots of custom bindings with the possibility that the binding is not present?
Say my html expression binds to image_url as below.

```
<span title="Company Logo" data-bind="image_url: company_banner"></span>
```

However there is every possibility that the image_url binding is not available.
In that case scenario, I'd just like to return a string value of company_banner.

Normally one would add a custom handler like below but if that handler is not available can we return some generic feedback?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.buttonLabel = {//update etc}
```

In our case the design may be ahead of the code, so we don't want ko to grumble.

Comment: Very good question, unfortunately don't have an answer. But I think you might want to dissect the ko library's bindingHandlers object in more details to see if you can do something there. But couldn't help but say very practical and good question

Comment: @Vin, yes just downloaded the debug version of ko now. Will post if I crack it.

Comment: @Vin, Looked through it. Fortunately someone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this scenario, I would look at using a custom binding provider.  Here is an article describing the functionality: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html.

So, I would create a custom binding provider that is a wrapper to the real binding provider.  Once the bindings are parsed, then we can inspect them to see if they exist in `ko.bindingHandlers`.  If one does not, then we can add a text binding with its value.

It might look like:

```
ko.lenientBindingProvider = function() {
   var realBindingProvider = new ko.bindingProvider();

   this.nodeHasBindings = realBindingProvider.nodeHasBindings;

   this.getBindings = function(node, bindingContext) {
       //parse the bindings with the real binding provider
       var result = realBindingProvider.getBindings(node, bindingContext);

       //inspect the returned bindings
       for (var binding in result) {
           if (result.hasOwnProperty(binding) && binding !== "_ko_property_writers" && !ko.bindingHandlers[binding]) {
                //add a text binding with whatever the missing binding was bound against
                result.text = result[binding];
           } 
       }

       return result;  
   };
};

ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ko.lenientBindingProvider();
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mMQKY/